# How to change tabviewitem header backgroud color in winui 3?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winui-3

```
<TabView x:Name="tabView" AddTabButtonClick="TabView_AddTabButtonClick" TabCloseRequested="TabView_TabCloseRequested" 
        SelectionChanged="TabView_SelectionChanged"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TabView.TabItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyTabItem">
            <TabViewItem Header="{x:Bind HeaderName, Mode=OneWay}" IconSource="{x:Bind IconSource, Mode=OneWay}" Content="{x:Bind Content}">
                <TabViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabViewItem.HeaderTemplate>
            </TabViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabView.TabItemTemplate>
</TabView>
```

I want to change the background color of TabViewItem header, however,
there is no property named `HeaderBackground` in **TabViewItem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundSelected` and `TabViewItemHeaderBackground` in Resources.

There are more header properties that can be changed here.

[microsoft-ui-xaml/TabView_themeresources.xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/8e41f536c0baa22f4a5d23bf20cfa82202c50452/dev/TabView/TabView_themeresources.xaml#L11)

> - TabViewItemHeaderBackground
> - TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundSelected
> - TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundPointerOver
> - TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundPressed
> - TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundDisabled

---

```
<TabView.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundSelected" Color="Red"/>
          <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabViewItemHeaderBackground" Color="Red"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</TabView.Resources>
```